# SQL Server 2008 R2 Database Diagram Error Code

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql, ssms, rdbms

I have sysadmin privileges on a SQL Server 2008 R2 server. I'm working with the development database and want to save a database diagram I created. When I try to save I get the following error message:

> ===================================

```
>String or binary data would be truncated.
>The statement has been terminated.
>The sp_creatediagram procedure attempted to return a status of `NULL`, which is not allowed. A status of 0 will be returned instead. (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)
```

---

```
Program Location: at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.DataTools.Interop.IDTDocTool.Save(Object dsRef, String path, Boolean okToOverwrite)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.Editors.DatabaseDesignerNode.Save(VSSAVEFLAGS dwSave, String strSilentSaveAsName, IVsUIShell pIVsUIShell, IntPtr punkDocDataIntPtr, String& strMkDocumentNew, Int32& pfCanceled)
```

I don't want to `ALTER` the database at all.

My goal is the save the diagram to references key relationships and other information in the future.

Does anyone know how I can enable saving the database diagram this way?

Answer (score 1):

This can happen if your database was created in a previous version of SQL Server. You need to recreate the table [dbo].[sysdiagrams] or if you do not want to lose already existing diagrams try this:

```
ALTER table [dbo].[sysdiagrams]
DROP COLUMN [diagram_id]

GO

ALTER table [dbo].[sysdiagrams]
ADD [diagram_id] [int] NOT NULL IDENTITY (1, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to migrate a diagram is to script it in the source database and recreate it one the destination. I do not remember where I have found the procedure below, but I have used several times to migrate diagrams between databases (even of different versions):

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM dbo.sysobjects WHERE id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[usp_ScriptDiagram]') AND OBJECTPROPERTY(id,N'IsProcedure') = 1)
    DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_ScriptDiagram]
GO  
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_ScriptDiagram](  
    @name VARCHAR(128))  
AS  
BEGIN  
    DECLARE @diagram_id     INT  
    DECLARE @index          INT  
    DECLARE @size           INT  
    DECLARE @chunk          INT  
    DECLARE @line           VARCHAR(max)  
    -- Set start index, and chunk 'constant' value  
    SET @index = 1  --   
    SET @chunk = 32    -- values that work: 2, 6  
                    -- values that fail: 15,16, 64  
    -- Get PK diagram_id using the diagram's name (which is what the user is familiar with)  
    SELECT   
        @diagram_id=diagram_id,  
        @size = DATALENGTH(definition)   
    FROM sysdiagrams   
    WHERE [name] = @name  
    IF @diagram_id IS NULL  
    BEGIN  
        PRINT '/*<error>  
Diagram name [' + @name + '] could not be found.  
</error>*/'   
    END  
    ELSE -- Diagram exists  
    BEGIN  
        PRINT '/*'  
        PRINT '<summary>'  
        PRINT 'Restore diagram ''' + @name + ''''  
        PRINT '</summary>'  
        PRINT '<generated>' + LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(23), GETDATE(), 121), 16) + '</generated>'  
        PRINT '*/'  
        PRINT 'PRINT ''=== Tool_ScriptDiagram2008 restore diagram [' + @name + '] ==='''  
        PRINT '    -- If the sysdiagrams table has not been created in this database, create it!  
                IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = ''sysdiagrams'')  
                BEGIN  
                    -- Create table script generated by Sql Server Management Studio  
                    -- _Assume_ this is roughly equivalent to what Sql Server/Management Studio  
                    -- creates the first time you add a diagram to a 2008 database  
                    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[sysdiagrams](  
                        [name] [sysname] NOT NULL,  
                        [principal_id] [int] NOT NULL,  
                        [diagram_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,  
                        [version] [int] NULL,  
                        [definition] [varbinary](max) NULL,  
                    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED   
                    (  
                        [diagram_id] ASC  
                    )WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ,  
                     CONSTRAINT [UK_principal_name] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED   
                    (  
                        [principal_id] ASC,  
                        [name] ASC  
                    )WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF)   
                    )   
                    EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N''microsoft_database_tools_support'', @value=1 , @level0type=N''SCHEMA'',@level0name=N''dbo'', @level1type=N''TABLE'',@level1name=N''sysdiagrams''  
                    PRINT ''[sysdiagrams] table was created as it did not already exist''  
                END  
                -- Target table will now exist, if it didn''t before'  
        PRINT 'SET NOCOUNT ON -- Hide (1 row affected) messages'  
        PRINT 'DECLARE @newid INT'  
        PRINT 'DECLARE @DiagramSuffix          varchar (50)'  
        PRINT ''  
        PRINT 'PRINT ''Suffix diagram name with date, to ensure uniqueness'''      
        PRINT 'SET @DiagramSuffix = '' '' + LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(23), GETDATE(), 121), 16)'  
        PRINT ''  
        PRINT 'PRINT ''Create row for new diagram'''  
        -- Output the INSERT that _creates_ the diagram record, with a non-NULL [definition],  
        -- important because .WRITE *cannot* be called against a NULL value (in the WHILE loop)  
        -- so we insert 0x so that .WRITE has 'something' to append to...  
        PRINT 'BEGIN TRY'  
        PRINT '    PRINT ''Write diagram ' + @name + ' into new row (and get [diagram_id])'''  
        SELECT @line =    
              '    INSERT INTO sysdiagrams ([name], [principal_id], [version], [definition])'  
            + ' VALUES (''' + [name] + '''+@DiagramSuffix, '+ CAST (principal_id AS VARCHAR(100))+', '+CAST (version AS VARCHAR(100))+', 0x)'  
        FROM sysdiagrams WHERE diagram_id = @diagram_id  
        PRINT @line  
        PRINT '    SET @newid = SCOPE_IDENTITY()'  
        PRINT 'END TRY'  
        PRINT 'BEGIN CATCH'  
        PRINT '    PRINT ''XxXxX '' + Error_Message() + '' XxXxX'''  
        PRINT '    PRINT ''XxXxX END Tool_ScriptDiagram2008 - fix the error before running again XxXxX'''  
        PRINT '    RETURN'  
        PRINT 'END CATCH'  
        PRINT ''  
        PRINT 'PRINT ''Now add all the binary data...'''  
        PRINT 'BEGIN TRY'  
        WHILE @index < @size  
        BEGIN  
            -- Output as many UPDATE statements as required to append all the diagram binary  
            -- data, represented as hexadecimal strings  
            SELECT @line =    
                 '    UPDATE sysdiagrams SET [definition] .Write ('  
                + ' ' + UPPER(sys.fn_varbintohexstr (SUBSTRING (definition, @index, @chunk)))  
                + ', null, 0) WHERE diagram_id = @newid -- index:' + CAST(@index AS VARCHAR(100))  
            FROM    sysdiagrams   
            WHERE    diagram_id = @diagram_id  
            PRINT @line  
            SET @index = @index + @chunk  
        END  
        PRINT ''  
        PRINT '    PRINT ''=== Finished writing diagram id '' + CAST(@newid AS VARCHAR(100)) + ''  ==='''  
        PRINT '    PRINT ''=== Refresh your Databases-[DbName]-Database Diagrams to see the new diagram ==='''  
        PRINT 'END TRY'  
        PRINT 'BEGIN CATCH'  
        PRINT '    -- If we got here, the [definition] updates didn''t complete, so delete the diagram row'  
        PRINT '    -- (and hope it doesn''t fail!)'  
        PRINT '    DELETE FROM sysdiagrams WHERE diagram_id = @newid'  
        PRINT '    PRINT ''XxXxX '' + Error_Message() + '' XxXxX'''  
        PRINT '    PRINT ''XxXxX END Tool_ScriptDiagram2008 - fix the error before running again XxXxX'''  
        PRINT '    RETURN'  
        PRINT 'END CATCH'  
    END  
END
```

**usage:**

exec [dbo].[usp_ScriptDiagram] ''